# LP Relaxation of Maximum Coverage Problem

Tags: linear-programming

So I know from some research I've done that the OPT-IP <= OPT-LP for the maximum coverage problem, however I'm having some difficulty following the explanations I find. Does an example exist where it can be shown OPT-IP < OPT-LP easily?

Comment: This question cannot be answered without, at the very least, knowledge of the specific linear program you are referring to. But more importantly, I would be *very* surprised if this is true. This would mean that the relaxed LP *never* picks an integer solution, and it's usually easy to show that there are edge cases where the integer solution is optimal; however, no one can know without the specific LP.

Comment: "following the explanations I find". It would be nice if you can provide a url or reference to the source. Are you able to pinpoint the first statement that you find it hard to follow?

Answer (score 1):

> Does an example exist where it can be shown OPT-IP < OPT-LP easily?

Here is an example of "LP Relaxation of Maximum Coverage Problem".

Let $G$ be the complete graph with four vertices, $\{v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4\}$. That is, $G$ has six edges. Let $S_i$ be the set of edges that is not incident to $v_i$. More specifically,
$S_1=\{\{v_1, v_2\},\{v_1, v_3\},\{v_1, v_4\}\}$.
$S_2=\{\{v_1, v_2\},\{v_2, v_3\},\{v_2, v_4\}\}$.
$S_3=\{\{v_1, v_3\},\{v_2, v_3\},\{v_3, v_4\}\}$.
$S_4=\{\{v_1, v_4\},\{v_2, v_4\},\{v_3, v_4\}\}$.

The maximum coverage problem is given the above 4 sets, select at most 2 of these sets such that the maximum number of elements are covered. The answer is to select any two sets, which will cover 5 elements. For example, if we select $S_1$ and $S_2$, then all edges are covered except edge $\{v_1,v_2\}$.

If we relax this integer linear programming problem to its corresponding general linear programming problem as done [here](https://people.seas.harvard.edu/~yaron/AM221-S16/lecture_notes/AM221_lecture22.pdf), we can select "half" of each set. Then each element is "covered" exactly once in total! For example, $\{v_1,v_2\}$ is covered by "half" of $S_3$ and "half" of $S_4$. So we are able to "cover" 6 elements, which are more than 5 elements.

As you should be able to see by now, the idea of this example is quite easy to understand and to generalize.

---

**Problem to ponder** (This is not an exercise.)
Is 5/6 the worst ratio we can get given any 4 sets?